# How should we interpret the phrase "asynchronous requests" in cfq-iosched.txt?

Tags: linux-kernel, io

The old [cfq-iosched.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.20/Documentation/block/cfq-iosched.txt) mentions "asynchronous" or "async" requests in several places.

> CFQ maintains the per process queue for the processes which request I/O
>   operation(synchronous requests). In case of asynchronous requests, all the
>   requests from all the processes are batched together according to their
>   process's I/O priority.

How exactly should we understand the distinction in this doc, from a userspace point of view?  I am unclear because there are several distinctions that are named sync/async:

1. Normal `read()`/`write()` calls, v.s. Linux AIO ([`io_submit()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/io_submit.2.html)/[`io_getevents`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/io_getevents.2.html)).
2. The `O_SYNC` flag, which can be set when you [`open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) a file.

(Note, as I understand it, [the quote above about IO priority does not apply to simple buffered writes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480862/ionice-does-not-have-any-effect-on-un-synced-writes-i-e-normal-writes). IO priority has no effect on such requests.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of requests processed by the Linux IO schedulers, have various "hints" set on them.  One of them is the "sync" hint.

> All IO is handled async in Linux. This is fine for background
>    writes, but for reads or writes that someone waits for completion
>    on, we want to notify the block layer and IO scheduler so that they
>    know about it. That allows them to make better scheduling
>    decisions. So when the below references 'sync' and 'async', it
>    is referencing this priority hint.
>
> -- [include/linux/fs.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/fs.h?id=6f6b29171a19#n155) (2016-11-01)

Read requests are always treated as synchronous.

> [block: don't use REQ_SYNC in the READ_SYNC definition](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=6f6b29171a19) (2016-11-01)
>
> Reads are synchronous per definition, don't add another flag for it.

Both `O_DIRECT` and `O_SYNC` writes are treated as synchronous.

```
#define READ_SYNC       0
#define WRITE_SYNC      (REQ_SYNC | REQ_NOIDLE)
#define WRITE_ODIRECT   REQ_SYNC
```

IO requests initiated by `fsync()` use the same hint as `O_SYNC` writes.  Although if the IO request has already been initiated and `fsync()` must wait for the existing request, I see no mechanism to adjust the request.

- [linux-4.20/source/fs/sync.c:347](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20/source/fs/sync.c#L347)
- [fs/sync.c: make sync_file_range(2) use WB_SYNC_NONE writeback](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/23d0127096cb)

> [Re: trying to understand READ_META, READ_SYNC, WRITE_SYNC & co](https://lists.openwall.net/linux-kernel/2010/06/21/334) (2010)
>
> > > But that leaves the question why disabling the idling logical for
> > >       data integrity ->writepage is fine?  This gets called from ->fsync
> > >       or O_SYNC writes and will have the same impact as O_DIRECT writes.
> >
> > We have never enabled idling for those. O_SYNC should get a nice
> >     boost too, it just needs to be benchmarked and tested and then
> >     there would be no reason not to add it.
>
> We've only started using any kind of sync tag last year in ->writepage
>   in commit a64c8610bd3b
>   ["block_write_full_page: Use synchronous writes for WBC_SYNC_ALL
>   writebacks"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=a64c8610bd3b)

"disabling idling" is a different hint flag, which is a bit harder to explain.   But the commit linked in the above quote confirms the use of the WRITE_SYNC hint for `fsync()`.

The code quoted above has since been moved or replaced, but the use of the "sync" hint should still be the same in 2018 as it was in 2016.

So I don't believe it really matters whether the requests are made using Linux AIO or not.

I notice AIO is only supported for O_DIRECT, therefore all AIO should be "synchronous" from the IO scheduler's point of view :-).  At least as of v4.20.  The [proposed new AIO interface](https://lwn.net/Articles/776703/) supports buffered (non-O_DIRECT) IO.  That will go through the same code above, so then the hint will still be set according to whether O_SYNC is used.

`sync_file_range()` is designed to allow triggering async writeback.  The current implementation (Linux v4.20) avoids setting `REQ_SYNC`, by using the writeback mode `WB_SYNC_NONE`.  This is true even when your program waits for the writeback by including the flag `SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WAIT_AFTER`.  However, kernels between v2.6.29 and v4.4 incorrectly used `WB_SYNC_ALL` and hence `REQ_SYNC` for all writeback triggered by `sync_file_range()`.