# CFQ - "In case of asynchronous requests, all the requests from all the processes are batched together according to their process's I/O priority"

Tags: linux-kernel, io

I think the following statements about CFQ contradict each other:

1. ["In case of asynchronous requests, all the requests from all the processes are batched together **according to their process's I/O priority**."](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.20/Documentation/block/cfq-iosched.txt)
2. [The only requests that the IO scheduler considers to be asynchronous are regular "buffered" writes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496886/29483).
3. "[`ionice` does nothing to de-prioritize asynchronous write IO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480862/ionice-does-not-have-any-effect-on-un-synced-writes-i-e-normal-writes)."

Which statements are incorrect?  Or if all of them are correct, why do they not contradict each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe statements 2 and 3 are incorrect.

It is possible for a user process to generate asynchronous write IOs using `sync_file_range()`.  Since these IOs are submitted directly by the calling process, they could be affected by the process' IO priority.

> sync_file_range() is designed to allow triggering async writeback. The current implementation (Linux v4.20) avoids setting REQ_SYNC, by using the writeback mode WB_SYNC_NONE. This is true even when your program waits for the writeback by including the flag SYNC_FILE_RANGE_WAIT_AFTER. (However, kernels between v2.6.29 and v4.4 incorrectly used WB_SYNC_ALL and hence REQ_SYNC for all writeback triggered by sync_file_range()).

I guess the process IO priority might also get used if it had to perform "direct reclaim" during an async write() call.  That was allegedly [gotten rid of in 2011](https://lwn.net/Articles/456904/).