# What does Fedora Workstation 29 use as the default I/O scheduler?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, io, scsi

If it depends on the exact type of block device, then what is the default I/O scheduler for each type of device?

### Background information

Fedora 29 includes a Linux kernel from the 4.19 series.  (Technically, the initial release used a 4.18 series kernel.  But a 4.19 kernel is installed by the normal software updates).

Starting in version 4.19, the mainline kernel has `CONFIG_SCSI_MQ_DEFAULT` as `default y`.  I.e. that's what you get if you take the tree published by Linus, without applying any Fedora-specific patches.  By default, SCSI and SATA devices will use the new multi-queue block layer.  (Linux treats SATA devices as being SCSI, using a translation based on the [SAT standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_/_ATA_Translation)).

This is a transitional step towards removing the old code.  All the old code will now be removed [in version <del>4.21</del> 5.0](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f382fb0bcef4c37dc049e9f6963e3baf204d815c), the next kernel release after 4.20.

In the new MQ system, block devices use a new set of I/O schedulers.  These include `none`, `mq-deadline`, and `bfq`.  In the mainline 4.19 kernel, the default scheduler is set as follows:

> [/* For blk-mq devices, we default to using mq-deadline, if available, for single
>   queue devices.  If deadline isn't available OR we have multiple queues,
>   default to "none". */](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19/source/block/elevator.c#L970)

A suggestion has been made to use BFQ as the default in place of `mq-deadline`.  This suggestion was not accepted for 4.19.

For the legacy SQ block layer, the default scheduler is CFQ, which is most similar to BFQ.

=> The kernel's default I/O scheduler can vary, depending on the type of device: SCSI/SATA, MMC/eMMC, etc.

CFQ attempts to support some level of "fairness" and I/O priorities (`ionice`).  It has various complexities.  BFQ is even more complex; it supports `ionice` but also has heuristics to classify and prioritize some I/O automatically.  `deadline` style scheduling is simpler; it does not support `ionice` at all.

=> Users with the Linux default kernel configuration, SATA devices, and no additional userspace policy (e.g. no `udev` rules), will be subject to a change in behaviour in 4.19.  Where `ionice` used to work, it will no longer have any effect.

However Fedora includes specific kernel patches / configuration.  Fedora also includes userspace policies such as default `udev` rules.

What does Fedora Workstation 29 use as the default I/O scheduler?  If it depends on the exact type of block device, then what is the default I/O scheduler for each type of device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora 29 ships with the **4.18.16** kernel. It appears that CFQ is the default.

```
$ grep CONFIG_DEFAULT_IOSCHED= /boot/config-4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64 
CONFIG_DEFAULT_IOSCHED="cfq"
$ grep CONFIG_SCSI_MQ_DEFAULT /boot/config-4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64 
# CONFIG_SCSI_MQ_DEFAULT is not set
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
noop deadline [cfq]
```

As of this writing (November 24, 2018), **4.19.3** is available as update for F29. But, the config options do not appear to have changed.

4.20.0 (RC1) is in the "Rawhide" devel tree. In that devel-tree kernel, CFQ is *still* the default, and `CONFIG_SCSI_MQ_DEFAULT` is still unset. The Fedora Kernel list at https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/kernel@lists.fedoraproject.org/ is the best place to discuss whether this should change.

Comment: I don't *think* we have any udev rules to change this; there'd need to be a special circumstance for us to do it that way rather than with kernel config, I think.

Comment: Thanks again! I asked because I have a spinning HDD and was not really convinced about the upstream default of mq-deadline :-).  I'm not hoping for Fedora to change - yet.  Because I haven't tried BFQ yet.  That might change soon :-).

Comment: If you're logged in to the web interface, you can post without subscribing to the list. Otherwise, yeah, you'll have to wait for moderation. (If that doesn't go through soon ping me and I'll find the appropriate person for that mailing list.)

Comment: Thanks @mattdm! I posted the message now. Laura Abott said she would look into enabling BFQ for 4.21. This will require either a udev rule or a kernel patch.  So we don't yet know exactly what will happen when Fedora moves to 4.21, but I'm very glad someone will be looking at this in advance. Link: https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/kernel@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/ZZLROUOL4LY3LMUKPFCOEVI376TTSARD/

Answer (score 3):

Some information that might be useful for your choice

I'm one of the authors of BFQ, so I'm all but a disinterested party :)
But I'll report only numbers obtained with repeatable test.

We have been testing BFQ on SD Cards, eMMC, HDDs, SATA SSDs,
and NVMe SSDs. As for HDDs and SSDs, we have run tests with both
single-disk and RAID configurations.

In terms of throughput, results can be summarized as follows. With SD
Cards, eMMC and HDDs (single and RAID), there is no regression in
terms of throughput. In contrast, with HDDs, there is a gain around
20-30% with some workload.

On SSDs, there is a loss of throughput only

- with random sync I/O: around 2-3 % on average SSDs, up to 10-15% on
  very fast NVMe SSDs. With a workload meant to put BFQ in the most
  difficult condition, we reached a loss of 18% [1], but in any other
  third-party test the loss is around 10% in the worst case. This loss
  is mainly due to the fact that BFQ is not a minimal I/O scheduler. We
  are working on this. It is not easy; we will need time to fill this
  gap.
- with only-write I/O on very fast SSDs: around 5-10%. This is due to a
  problem with I/O-request tags. We have already found a solution.
  Since we do not consider this issue critical, we are giving more
  priority to other items in our TODO list. If you think otherwise, we
  are willing to change our priorities.

Because of the above overhead, BFQ cannot process more than 400-500
KIOPS on a commodity CPU.

In terms of responsiveness and latency for time-sensitive applications
(such as audio/video players), results are simply incomparable. For
example, regardless of the I/O workload in the background, with BFQ
applications start as quickly as if the drive was idle. With any of the
other schedulers, applications may take ten times as long, or even not
start at all (until the background workload is over) [1].

In addition, as for server-like workloads, BFQ enable, e.g., the desired fraction of the I/O bandwidth to be guaranteed to each client (or container, VM, or any
other kind of entity sharing storage), while reaching a total throughput not
comparable to that reached by any other solution for controlling I/O [2].

Finally, if you are in doubt about some particular workload, we will
be glad to test it.

[1] http://algo.ing.unimo.it/people/paolo/disk_sched/results.php

[2] https://lwn.net/Articles/763603/