# did `dd` buffer entire ~700MB iso image?

Tags: dd, pv

I read that to transfer an iso image to a pendrive and print progress I should execute pipeline below.

```
$ dd if=$IMG bs=4M | pv -s 668M | sudo dd of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
```

`pv` should print and update a progress bar in terminal. However, my progress bar jumped to 100% and the command hanged. I could not kill the `dd` writing to the pendrive so I looked under the hood.

journal

```
Jan 13 01:57:32 nixos systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 3min)!
Jan 13 01:57:32 nixos systemd[1]: systemd-udevd.service: Killing process 1830 (systemd-udevd) with signal SIGABRT.
Jan 13 01:57:54 nixos sudo[3787]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 13 01:57:54 nixos kernel:  sdc: sdc1 sdc2
```

iotop

```
    TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND                                                                                       
   1830 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % systemd-udevd
   3788 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % dd of=/dev/sdc bs=4M
      8 be/4 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 % 99.99 % [kworker/u64:0+flush-8:32]
```

I tried with sudo or as root. Same effect. `pv` shows 100% immediately but `dd of=...` blocks for about 3 minutes. That is not consistent with what I read on the internet and saw myself on other machines. What happened?

PS.

```
$ sudo hdparm -W /dev/sdc

/dev/sdc:
 write-caching = not supported
```

PPS.
Tried `status=progress` - same effect (100% and hangs until write is complete).

Comment: You'd be better off using `sudo sh -c 'pv >/dev/sdc' <"$IMG"`. More efficient and less prone to short reads on the pipe causing a mis-write

Comment: Google for "Linux dirty buffers".

Comment: Also this command is total bonkers, this is how I run it: `pv -petrab file > destination`. No need to pipe **twice** and use three commands instead of one. Also, just also `dd` can actually slow down things.

Comment: Also read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480399/why-were-usb-stick-stall-problems-reported-in-2013-why-wasnt-this-problem-so - this might be exactly what you're experiencing.