# Progress bar for ejecting USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, usb-drive, eject

OS is Debian 10. File manager is Thunar.

I've noticed that when I copy a few dozen gigabytes to my USB flash drive, the process only takes a minute or two. Then when I go to eject, the ejection process can take an hour or more. The USB drive is fine, it's just a lot of data to flush from the disk cache.

The issue is this: I have no clue how much time is left on the ejection process.

There **must** be a way to see the progress on this. Or better yet, is there a way to copy files to a USB flash drive and skip the disk cache entirely, just for that physical device?

I know how to skip the disk cache for `dd`, but that is useless here.

And of course, `sync` has no progress bar and as far as I know doesn't allow you specify a physical device.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Thunar (for anything else than getting an overview of a gallery), so I don't know how it handles mounting, it might use this "fancy" new thing called udisks2.

A solution might be to mount the device with the `sync` option, in the good old days that would have been handled through `/etc/fstab`, if whatever Thunar uses honors that, it's still doable, else you'll have to figure out if it can be configured some other way.

Answer (score 1):

You've discovered [Why were "USB-stick stall" problems reported in 2013? Why wasn't this problem solved by the existing "No-I/O dirty throttling" code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480399/why-were-usb-stick-stall-problems-reported-in-2013-why-wasnt-this-problem-so)

How to solve it? Unforuntately Linux doesn't allow to have dirty buffers per device, so here's I how I solved it for myself (per Linux Torvalds advice):

```
cat /etc/sysctl.d/limit_dirty_buffers.conf
# Per Torvalds advice
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 33554432
vm.dirty_bytes = 134217728
```

syncing periodically is not the best idea as it causes higher tear and wear and slows down the process even further.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be to run a daemon doing [sync(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) calls every few seconds. This could slow down your entire Linux system.

My [sync-periodically.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/sync-periodically.c) program is such a daemon. GPLv3+ licensed, so *NO WARRANTY* and you could lose all your data. You got the source code, and you could improve it.

It is a command line, not a GUI interface, program (no progress bar). You might start it from `/etc/crontab` - see [crontab(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).

PS. Contact me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net` (near Paris, in France) for details.